# Server 2003 saying unlicensed

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, licensing

I came in this morning to our windows 2003 server - running only SQL server 2005 saying it was unlicensed.
When logged straight onto the box as soon as I got past the login, it popped up the click yes to license, did that and it would just loop back around to the login.

It wouldn't turn off, couldn't remote to it, after a power off and reboot, it magically decided it was in fact licensed.
It didn't appear to be low on disc space or other resources. Logs not showing anything out of the ordinary.

Has anyone else experienced this, or might have an idea as to what just happened?

Any help much appreciated.